# How do I select a value based on two conditions from a data frame and then paste it into a cell in another data frame?

Tags: r

I have two data frames. One has trials in which two objects appeared. Another has information on how those two objects relate (visual similarity). For each row (trial) in the first data frame, I would like to pull the names of the objects and use them to look up specific rows in the second data frame. They look like this:

```
  Trial probepic target_pic vissim
1     1  Robot1    Robot6     NA
2     2  Robot1    Robot3     NA
3     3  Robot5    Robot6     NA
4     4  Robot2    Robot1     NA
5     5  Robot3    Robot9     NA
6     6  Robot14   Robot9     NA

    Rob1   Rob2  sim
1 Robot1 Robot1   NA
2 Robot2 Robot1 2.88
3 Robot3 Robot1 3.75
4 Robot4 Robot1 1.63
5 Robot5 Robot1 3.63
6 Robot6 Robot1 2.50
```

etc.
What I want is to use the probepic and target_pic variables to select a value of sim from the second data frame and paste it into vissim in the first data frame. I've been playing around with subset and I can get the correct value using this code:

```
subset(vissim, Rob1=="Robot1" & Rob2=="Robot2")$sim
```

But I want to use the `probepic` and `target_pic` variables for each row instead of "Robot1" and "Robot2." And finally to apply the function for each row in the first data frame. So, in each row, the function would look in the `probepic` column and match the value to the `Rob1` column and then look in the `target_pic` column and match that value to the `Rob2` column. This would specify a unique row in the second data frame. Then, it would take the value of `sim` from that unique row and paste it into `vissim`.

Comment: what is the expected output look like ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to merge the data sets together. Try the following:

```
newDf <- merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("probepic", "target_pic"), by.y=c("Rob1", "Rob2"), all=T)
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(header=T, text="  Trial probepic target_pic vissim
1  Robot1    Robot6     NA
2  Robot1    Robot3     NA
3  Robot5    Robot6     NA
4  Robot2    Robot1     NA
5  Robot3    Robot9     NA
6  Robot14   Robot9     NA")

df2 <- read.table(header= T, text="    Rob1   Rob2  sim
Robot1 Robot1   NA
Robot2 Robot1 2.88
Robot3 Robot1 3.75
Robot4 Robot1 1.63
Robot5 Robot1 3.63
Robot6 Robot1 2.50")
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! I was worried merge wouldn't be the correct function because df1 has multiple instances of Robot1,Robot2 rows, for example, but it copied the correct value of `sim` for each row.